# Activity Time Incorrect in Drupal Views

Tags: civicase, activities, drupal-views

I just created a Drupal 7 Views report to show the date and time when the user created a case activity. The date is correct. However, I entered this activity at 11:09 am this morning, but Views show the time as 7:08pm. I produced the same report in SearchKit and the time there is correct. Is the problem related to Views? I double checked that the date timezone is correct in "Default site/user timezone".

Drupal, PHP, and MySQL timezones match. The activity_created_date table also lists the correct info:  2021-12-24 11:09. Not sure why Views is producing the time as 7:08 pm instead of 11:09 am.

My temporary fix right now is use Global:PHP and subtract 8 hours manually. Although this works, I can't expose this date field for filtering results.

```
<?php
$hoursToSubtract = 8;
$timeToSubtract = ($hoursToSubtract * 60 * 60);
$timeInPast = ($row->created_date - $timeToSubtract);
echo date("m/d/Y g:ia", $timeInPast);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a bunch of views set up that report on civi activities. I recall having some issues with the created date and ended up swapping to the scheduled activity date. Which I know sounds counter-intuitive but it was more accurate for me (we do a lot of creating scheduled activities and then completing them later). It also allowed me to use just one date field even when showing both complete and scheduled activities!